# A lower bound on the largest eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I am trying to prove the following:

---

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_n$; the sum all entries in $A$ is $s$. Prove that $\lambda_1\geq\frac{s}{n}$.

---

I have tried the following: because of symmetry, we have

\begin{equation}
n\lambda_1^2 \geq \lambda_1^2 + \cdots + \lambda_n^2 = \mbox{Trace}(M^2)=\sum_{i,j}(M_{i,j})^2 \geq \frac{s^2}{n^2},
\end{equation}

by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Therefore,

\begin{equation}
\lambda_1^2\geq\frac{s^2}{n^3} \Longrightarrow \lambda_1\geq\frac{s}{n\sqrt{n}}.
\end{equation}

This is the best I can get, I appreciate any corrections and hints to the result $s/n$.

Comment: Try using $\lambda_1\ge \lambda_i$ in the condition $\sum \lambda_i=s$

Comment: @Exodd But $s$ is the sum of all entries in $A$, not the trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The [Courant-Fischer Theorem](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Ebgb/Courses/Math6304/MatrixTheory-20121011.pdf) gives that
$$\lambda_1=\max_{v}\frac{v^\intercal Mv}{v^\intercal v}.$$
Can you think of a vector $v$ for which $v^\intercal Mv=s$ and $v^\intercal v=n$?

Comment: Oh I see, I can choose $v$ with the vector of all ones! Thanks a lot!